# Bootstrap columns squished

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need some help, or advice rather. I've been working on creating a really basic recruitment portal for my employer. However it would seem like I'm not setting up the bootstrap scaffolding correctly as the columns seem to be very 'squashed' together when looking at it from a smaller device.
  What is confusing me is the fact that I've used xs columns, which I would have assumed would take smaller devices into consideration and as such would adjust the width's of the columns accordingly...

I'd really appreciate it if someone could either tell me what I'm doing wrong or show me how to fix it to make it more responsive.

Here is a [pen to a working example](http://codepen.io/Todai/pen/QKGBQK) and below are the columns (without headers):

```
   <div class="row buffer-top">
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1 text-center">
         <div class="thumbnail">
            <span class="fa-stack fa-4x"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-siteAccess"></i><i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-clipboard fa-stack-1x"></i></span>
            <div class="caption">
               <h3>Site Access Controllers</h3>
               <p><strong>Location:</strong> UK-wide</p>
               <p><a href="portals/0/resources/pdf/placeholder.pdf" target="blank" class="btn btn-default" role="button">More info</a><a href="mailto:joakim.kakaei@jaberoconsulting.com" target="_blank"class="btn btn-default" role="button">Apply</a></p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1 text-center">
         <div class="thumbnail">
            <span class="fa-stack fa-4x"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-developers"></i><i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-code fa-stack-1x"></i></span>
            <div class="caption">
               <h3>Software Developers</h3>
               <p><strong>Location:</strong> Tunbridge Wells</p>
               <p><a href="portals/0/resources/pdf/softwarePlaceholder.pdf" target="blank" class="btn btn-default" role="button">More info</a><a href="mailto:joakim.kakaei@jaberoconsulting.com" target="_blank" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Apply</a></p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1 text-center">
         <div class="thumbnail">
            <span class="fa-stack fa-4x"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-office"></i><i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-building-o fa-stack-1x"></i></span>
            <div class="caption">
               <h3>Site Access Manager</h3>
               <p><strong>Location:</strong> UK-wide</p>
               <p><a href="portals/0/resources/pdf/hOfficePlaceholder.pdf" target="blank" class="btn btn-default" role="button">More info</a><a href="mailto:joakim.kakaei@jaberoconsulting.com" target="_blank" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Apply</a></p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1 text-center">
         <div class="thumbnail">
            <span class="fa-stack fa-4x"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-consultant"></i><i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-question fa-stack-1x"></i></span>
            <div class="caption">
               <h3>Site Consultants</h3>
               <p><strong>Location:</strong> UK-Wide</p>
               <p><a href="portals/0/resources/pdf/consultantPlaceholder.pdf" target="blank" class="btn btn-default" role="button">More info</a><a href="mailto:joakim.kakaei@jaberoconsulting.com" target="_blank" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Apply</a></p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? Should the circles get smaller? Should they split into multiple rows?

Comment: The circles size could persist (as the widths are static), but the offset should be better formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code and see [Bootply Demo](http://www.bootply.com/yJHMS10e00)

You can add **col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12**

**col-lg-3 for large device,
col-md-3 for medium device, 
col-sm-6 for small-medium device, 
col-xs-12 for mobile device**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
         <div class="circle one">
            <div class="table-row"> <span>Site Access </span> </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
         <div class="circle two">
            <div class="table-row"> <span>Developers</span> </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
         <div class="circle three">
            <div class="table-row"> <span>Head Office </span> </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
         <div class="circle four">
            <div class="table-row"> <span>Consultants </span> </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row buffer-top">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 text-center">
         <div class="thumbnail">
            <span class="fa-stack fa-4x"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-siteAccess"></i><i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-clipboard fa-stack-1x"></i></span>
            <div class="caption">
               <h3>Site Access Controllers</h3>
               <p><strong>Location:</strong> UK-wide</p>
               <p><a href="portals/0/resources/pdf/placeholder.pdf" target="blank" class="btn btn-default" role="button">More info</a><a href="mailto:joakim.kakaei@jaberoconsulting.com" target="_blank" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Apply</a></p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 text-center">
         <div class="thumbnail">
            <span class="fa-stack fa-4x"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-developers"></i><i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-code fa-stack-1x"></i></span>
            <div class="caption">
               <h3>Software Developers</h3>
               <p><strong>Location:</strong> Tunbridge Wells</p>
               <p><a href="portals/0/resources/pdf/softwarePlaceholder.pdf" target="blank" class="btn btn-default" role="button">More info</a><a href="mailto:joakim.kakaei@jaberoconsulting.com" target="_blank" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Apply</a></p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 text-center">
         <div class="thumbnail">
            <span class="fa-stack fa-4x"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-office"></i><i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-building-o fa-stack-1x"></i></span>
            <div class="caption">
               <h3>Site Access Manager</h3>
               <p><strong>Location:</strong> UK-wide</p>
               <p><a href="portals/0/resources/pdf/hOfficePlaceholder.pdf" target="blank" class="btn btn-default" role="button">More info</a><a href="mailto:joakim.kakaei@jaberoconsulting.com" target="_blank" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Apply</a></p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 text-center">
         <div class="thumbnail">
            <span class="fa-stack fa-4x"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-consultant"></i><i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-question fa-stack-1x"></i></span>
            <div class="caption">
               <h3>Site Consultants</h3>
               <p><strong>Location:</strong> UK-Wide</p>
               <p><a href="portals/0/resources/pdf/consultantPlaceholder.pdf" target="blank" class="btn btn-default" role="button">More info</a><a href="mailto:joakim.kakaei@jaberoconsulting.com" target="_blank" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Apply</a></p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Jainman, probably because you have posted code without explaining it

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin please see my full answer i have explain it in my answer, so please you can check again and let me know.

Comment: This is the solution I like the most. Is there anyway to give the columns some offset if the device is smaller? Meaning that the columns shouldn't be hugging the left side of the screen when on an xs device.

Comment: @Jainam I wasn't the one who downvoted, I just assumed the reason.

Comment: @geostocker you have already used `col-xs-offset-1`, use it again. Increase the value if you like

Comment: The problem is that it seems as if the offset is used regardless of the size of the client's device. 
What I mean is that it looks great if I use a md/lg, but if I use an xs/sm device I want the offset to be used. Not otherwise.
So right now if I add the offset the fourth column is on a different row:
http://www.worksiteclouddev.com/Jobs.aspx

Comment: You can remove all col-xs-offset-1 class from your div than after you have seen output..

Comment: And you can given css in this class .circle {  margin: 0 auto;} and .thumbnail {  margin: 0 auto;}

Answer (score 0):

col-xs-* classes will persist the layout in smaller widths. You need to use col-sm-* classes. They will break at 767px, so that in smaller devices there will be enough space to show the whole div horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

You can divide it in groups of two, for smaller screens and I guess it looks better without the offset (you could need to adjust your CSS code I guess, since I've seen some margins there): http://codepen.io/denea/pen/EgNprZ

```
<div class="row buffer-top">
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 text-center">
         <div class="thumbnail">
            <span class="fa-stack fa-4x"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-siteAccess"></i><i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-clipboard fa-stack-1x"></i></span>
            <div class="caption">
               <h3>Site Access Controllers</h3>
               <p><strong>Location:</strong> UK-wide</p>
               <p><a href="portals/0/resources/pdf/placeholder.pdf" target="blank" class="btn btn-default" role="button">More info</a><a href="mailto:joakim.kakaei@jaberoconsulting.com" target="_blank"class="btn btn-default" role="button">Apply</a></p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 text-center">
         <div class="thumbnail">
            <span class="fa-stack fa-4x"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-developers"></i><i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-code fa-stack-1x"></i></span>
            <div class="caption">
               <h3>Software Developers</h3>
               <p><strong>Location:</strong> Tunbridge Wells</p>
               <p><a href="portals/0/resources/pdf/softwarePlaceholder.pdf" target="blank" class="btn btn-default" role="button">More info</a><a href="mailto:joakim.kakaei@jaberoconsulting.com" target="_blank" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Apply</a></p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 text-center">
         <div class="thumbnail">
            <span class="fa-stack fa-4x"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-office"></i><i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-building-o fa-stack-1x"></i></span>
            <div class="caption">
               <h3>Site Access Manager</h3>
               <p><strong>Location:</strong> UK-wide</p>
               <p><a href="portals/0/resources/pdf/hOfficePlaceholder.pdf" target="blank" class="btn btn-default" role="button">More info</a><a href="mailto:joakim.kakaei@jaberoconsulting.com" target="_blank" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Apply</a></p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 text-center">
         <div class="thumbnail">
            <span class="fa-stack fa-4x"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-consultant"></i><i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-question fa-stack-1x"></i></span>
            <div class="caption">
               <h3>Site Consultants</h3>
               <p><strong>Location:</strong> UK-Wide</p>
               <p><a href="portals/0/resources/pdf/consultantPlaceholder.pdf" target="blank" class="btn btn-default" role="button">More info</a><a href="mailto:joakim.kakaei@jaberoconsulting.com" target="_blank" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Apply</a></p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

And for CSS:

```
.thumbnail {
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 350px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```